# Cytoscape.js: style doesn't apply

Tags: javascript, ember.js, cytoscape.js

I am using Cytoscape.js in Ember app. I have created a component for graph. I try to set graph stylesheet in the `didInsertElement` function of the component like this:

```
        this.get("cy").style()
            .selector('node')
              .css({
                'width': '100px',
                'height': '100px',
                'border-color': 'gray',
                'border-width': 3,
                'border-opacity': 0.5
              })
            // unimportant code here
            .selector('.faded')
              .css({
                'opacity': 0.0,
                'text-opacity': 0
            }).update();
```

When I access route with this component in Ember, the style isn't applied (however layout and other things are working properly). When I transit to another route and than back, style magically appears.

What am I doing wrong? How to apply the style on "first load"?

EDIT: Full code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/XYF4FaAF)
The handlebars code is simple:

```
<div class="container content-section" id="graph-content">
<div class="centre" style="margin: 10px">
    <!-- cytoscape graph -->
    <div id="cy"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you setup demo on ember-twiddle.com or emberjs.jsbin.com or at least share whole component code?

Comment: I added link to full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - it was my mistake. The style of node is based on `category`, which belongsTo node and is loaded asynchronously. When I insert nodes into the graph, the nodes promise is already fullfiled, however the nested relationships aren't fullfilled yet, so the node style is `undefined`.